# 2020 Kia Sportage 2.4l wobbling crankshaft pulley

Tags: kia, sportage, crankshaft-pulley

I am considering purchasing a used 2020 Kia Sportage with the 2.4 liter engine. I opened the hood when it was idling and noticed the crankshaft pulley was wobbling. It wasn't making any noise and it was running fine.

I mentioned this to the the dealership and they agreed it was an issue and said they will send it to the Kia dealer to get repaired.

Assuming they do that and can show me the paperwork, my question is should I be concerned that the wobble was a symptom of any larger problem? I'm wondering if I should avoid purchasing this vehicle because of this.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Considering it's fairly much a new vehicle (you didn't put down the mileage), all of this should be covered under manufacturer's warranty. I don't think I'd worry about it too much. If you purchase the vehicle, you should continue to have the remainder of the factory coverage. As long as you've still got some room on it, I don't think I'd worry about it too much. It should have at least 5yr/60k mile warranty. As long as the mileage isn't more thank 60k, you've got that room I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks, Paulster2. It's got about 36k miles. It's a rental.